# Finding the Adjoint Operator Under Inner-Products: Behaviour of Provided Function Values.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I've been solving these types of adjoint operator problems:

> Find the adjoint of $\mathcal{L}(f)(t) = \dfrac{df}{dt} + e^tf$ with $f(1) = 0$ under the inner-product $\langle\ f , g \rangle = \int^1_{-1} f(t)g(t) \ dt$.

The solutions for such problems follow this line of reasoning:

We need to find the operator $\mathcal{L}^\dagger$, such that $\langle\ \mathcal{L}f , g \rangle = \langle\ f , \mathcal{L}^\dagger g \rangle$.

$\langle\ \mathcal{L}f , g \rangle = \int_0^1 ( f' + e^tf)g \ dt$

$= \int_{-1}^1 f'g \ dt \int_{-1}^1 e^tfg \ dt$

*Using integration by parts:*

$= [fg]_{-1}^1 - \int^1_{-1} fg' \ dt + \int_{-1}^1 e^tfg \ dt$

$= 0 - f(-1)g(-1) + \int_{-1}^1 (-g' + e^tg)f \ dt$

and hence we need $\mathcal{L}^\dagger(g)(t) = -\dfrac{dg}{dt} + e^tg$ and $g(-1) = 0$.

In the solutions for these adjoint operator problems, we always end up with the product of some functions (in the above case, we had $f(-1)g(-1)$). And in this situation, I have noticed that we **always** set a function **other than the one provided in the problem statement** to $0$ (in this case, we set $g(-1) = 0$ instead of $f(-1) = 0$, since we had $f(1) = 0$ in the problem statement.

I will provide another example for the sake of clarity:

> Find the adjoint of $\mathcal{L}(f)(t) = t\dfrac{df}{dt} + 2f$ with $f(0) = 3$ under the inner-product $\langle\ f , g \rangle = \int^1_{0} f(t)g(t) \ dt$.

$\langle\ \mathcal{L}f , g \rangle = \int_0^1 (tf' + 2f)g \ dt = \int^1_0 (tg)f' \ dt + \int^1_0 2fg \ dt$

$= [tgf]^1_0 - \int^1_0 (tg)' f \ dt + \int_0^1 2fg \ dt$

$= g(1)f(1) + \int^1_0 [-(tg)' + 2g] f \ dt = g(1)f(1) + \int^1_0 (-tg' + g)f \ dt$

and hence we need $g(1) = 0$ and $\mathcal{L}^\dagger(g)(t) = -t \dfrac{dg}{dt} + g$.

In this case, we had $f$ in the problem statement, and so we chose $g$ such that $g(1) = 0$ instead of $f(1) = 0$.

**My question is, why is this the case? Why do we always set a function other than the one in the problem statement to equal $0$ and do the cancelling in our calculations?** I'm sure there is a theoretical reason for this, but I have not encountered any reasoning for this.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us stick to your first example. You have there
$$
\langle\mathcal Lf,g\rangle = \langle f,-g'+e^tg\rangle - f(-1)g(-1).
$$
Let $g$ be such that $\mathcal L^\dagger g$ is defined. Then, as $\langle f,\mathcal L^\dagger g\rangle = \langle\mathcal Lf,g\rangle$, we would have, putting $h := \mathcal L^\dagger g + g'-e^tg$,
$$\tag{$*$}
\langle f,h\rangle = -f(-1)g(-1).
$$
This holds for all $f$. In particular, $h=0$ is equivalent to $g(-1)=0$. Now, ($*$) implies (setting $a := |g(-1)|$)
$$
a|f(-1)|\le\|h\|\|f\|
$$
for all $f$. But in fact, there are sequences $f_n$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ but $|f_n(-1)|\to\infty$ (can you think of one?). Hence, $a=0$ and thus $g(-1) = 0$ (which also gives $h=0$ and thus $\mathcal L^\dagger g = -g'+e^tg$).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please clarify why $\langle f,h\rangle = -f(-1)g(-1)$?

Comment: Everything's there that you need. It's all in lines 2 and 3

Comment: Actually, It makes sense to me now.

Comment: There you go. It is actually a trivial thing.

Comment: With regards to the sequences, I could be misunderstanding this, but It seems to me like an infinite orthonormal basis, such as the Fourier basis, would be what you are alluding to? Or rather, a "Fourier sequence"?

Comment: If $f_n$ is the Fourier sequence in $L^2(-1,1)$, then $|f_n(-1)|$ is constant. So, no. Think of a function for which $f(-1) = n$ and then it goes down towards the $x$-axis quite quickly (say linearly) and then remains zero until $t=1$, so that the integral of $f_n^2$ is $1$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of anything. Regardless, I think I understand now. Your proof was well-constructed and illuminating. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what's misunderstandable in my description, but ok... For $n\in\mathbb N$ define the function $g_n(t) = n - \frac{n^2}2(1+t)$ and set $f_n(t) := \sqrt{g_n(t)}$ for $-1\le t\le -1+\tfrac 2 n$ and $f_n(t) = 0$ elsewhere. Then $\int_{-1}^1|f_n|^2\,dt = 1$ for all $n$ and $f_n(-1) = \sqrt n\to\infty$.